# Scroll to the top of section (.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i writing in java script, that when i click on just Read less button jump to the first element, i solved that with this code >> toggle_switch[0].scrollIntoView(false)
it jumps up to where the button in read less position is, but i wanna set the position totally top of button where the first element (div) is

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
      var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
      var toggle_switch = $(this);
      $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
          if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
              toggle_switch.html('Read More');
              
          } else {
              toggle_switch.html('Read Less');
          }
         
      });
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-12 text-center pb-5 pt-5">Aktionen</h1>


        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_7.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_6.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_5.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="collapse" style="display:none">

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_20.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_12.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_11.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" href="#collapse" class="btn btn-secondary nav-toggle">Read More</button></div>
      </div>
      
      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution without any library or framework:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

you can calculate the exact position of the div you want to scroll-to

```
const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
  elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
  offset   = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;
```

an than use the variable "offset" in the scroll() function.
top: offset

Edit:

javascript:

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const elementToShow = document.querySelector(".element-to-show");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (btn.textContent === "Read More") {
  btn.textContent = "Read Less";
  elementToShow.style.display="flex";
  }
  else if (btn.textContent === "Read Less") {
   btn.textContent = "Read More";
   elementToShow.style.display="none";
   const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
      elemRect = document.querySelector(".target-container").getBoundingClientRect(),
      offset   = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;
   window.scroll({
   top: offset,
   left: 0,
   behavior: 'smooth'
   });
  }
});
```

just add this class to your element, wich you want to be seen/not seen

```
.element-to-show {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="row  element-to-show" id="collapse" >

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
```

also add the class ".target-container" to the div to wich you want to scroll to.

and remove the styling in the HTML file. styling in html has the highest priority so it overwrites the external styles.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const elementToShow = document.querySelector(".element-to-show");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (btn.textContent === "Read More") {
    btn.textContent = "Read Less";
    elementToShow.style.display="flex";
  }
  else if (btn.textContent === "Read Less") {
    btn.textContent = "Read More";
    elementToShow.style.display="none";
    const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
  elemRect = document.querySelector(".target-container").getBoundingClientRect(),
  offset   = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;

    
    window.scroll({
    top: offset,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  }
})
```

```css
.element-to-show {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<section>
    <div class="container target-container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-12 text-center pb-5 pt-5">Aktionen</h1>


        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_7.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_6.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_5.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row  element-to-show" id="collapse" >

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_20.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_12.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 aktion-text">
          <h2></h2>
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="image/Bild_11.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2 class="center">Industrie</h2>
        </div>

        
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" href="#collapse" class="btn btn-secondary nav-toggle">Read More</button></div>
      </div>
      
      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can u please edit my code and write it there? Because i tested now and didnt work! it would be nice from you

Comment: sorry, but i doesn’t work

u can test ur solution in my code and see what i mean and why doesn’t work